# Email send not using most recent updated version of data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

Trying to resolve issue where when sending using automation email does not use most recent “updated” version of data extension. Have attempted to use a regular DE, as well as filtered and query to create DE. What is occurring is that when a record is added to DE it is sending correct, but when record is updated (e.g. update email address field) record sends using original email address field contents.

Do I need to add AMPScript to email body to make email send use most up-to-date version of data extension? Or can this issue be solved without using AMPScript? Is so how?

Comment: How is the de getting updated?  When does it happen? Any code you can share?

Comment: There is an account configuration option that is likely the cause of the issue that you are seeing.  Please contact Global Support to have this adjusted so that the updated email address is sent to: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/contact_us/

Comment: Hey - that looks like an answer - go ahead and add it below :O)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an account configuration option that is likely the cause of the issue that you are seeing. Please contact Global Support to have this adjusted so that the updated email address is sent to: help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/contact_us